# MySQL - Show Status details for specific connection IDs

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I would like to check character set details for each of the active connections on a Mysql server.

```
show full processlist
```

Will give me each of the connected processes.  And,

```
status
```

will give me the details for my own connection.  However, I want to get the "status" of each process, so I can see the character set details for each process.  I haven't been able to find a way to do this.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with MySQL 5.7, this is instrumented in the performance_schema.

See table `performance_schema.status_by_thread`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-status-variable-tables.html